# How to make it so a mentionedMember can be the author at default (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I'm wanting it so you basically can do -userinfo (and mention nobody) and it sets the var mentionedMember to the author, but when I do this it interferes with the guildMember "thing/option" which limits me to not using .joinedAt() how do I get around this?
Here's my code:

```
        if (!mentionedUser || !mentionedMember) {
            mentionedUser = message.author
            mentionedMember = message.author << set the mentionedMember to the author
        }
```

Heres the embed:

```
                { name: 'Joined', value: mentionedMember.joinedAt.toUTCString(), inline: true },
```

Comment: > which limits me to not using .joinedAt()
I mean it will return undefined*

Answer (score 0):

Had to replace message.author with message.member

Answer (score 0):

show all of the code first of all but how I used to do it it was something like
`const user = msg.mentions.members.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.get(arguments[0]) || msg.member;`

arguments[0] is just the first word after the command
also msg can be message to you

```
const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    commands: ["user-info", "ui"],
    minArgs: 0,
    maxArgs: 1,
    callback: (msg, arguments, text) => {
        const user = msg.mentions.members.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.get(arguments[0]) || msg.member;

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${user.user.username}`)
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setThumbnail(user.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .addFields(
                {name: "Name: ", value: user.user.username, inline: true},
                {name: "#️⃣ Tag: ", value: `#${user.user.discriminator}`, inline: true},
                {name: " ID: ", value: user.user.id, inline: true},
                {name: " Is Bot: ", value: user.user.bot, inline: true},
                {name: "Creation Date: ", value: user.user.createdAt.toLocaleDateString("en-us"), inline: true},
                {name: "Joined Date: ", value: user.joinedAt.toLocaleDateString("en-us"), inline: true},
                {name: "User Roles: ", value: user.roles.cache.map((role) => role.toString()).join(" ,"), inline: true}
            );
        msg.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

this is all of my code